# Mouse position offset problem in a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have several problems. I don't understand why in this code, if I click on matrix, I do have a grid that starts at x=30, and y=30. But if I click on create grid, the grid is shifted, moreover the mouse click does not blacken the right box. There is also a problem because there is always a spinbox when it should be deleted by grille_frame.delete("all").

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
btn_frame = tk.Frame(root)
btn_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
grille_frame = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=600)
grille_frame.grid(row=1, column = 0)
yscrollbar_grille = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=grille_frame.yview)
yscrollbar_grille.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=3, sticky="ns")
xscrollbar_grille = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=grille_frame.xview)
xscrollbar_grille.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
grille_frame.config(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar_grille.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar_grille.set)
rows = 12
cols = 12
cell_size = 40
x = 30
y = 30

def zoom():
    grille_frame.scale("all", 30, 30, 0.5, 0.5)

scale_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame, text="scale", command=zoom)
scale_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

def mouse_position(event):
    grille_frame.event_generate("<Motion>", warp=True, x=30, y=30)
    print("mouse position on canvas", event.x, event.y)
    print("mouse postition on screen", event.x_root, event.y_root)
    

root.bind("<Key>", mouse_position)
def matrice():
    grille_frame.delete("all")
    y = 30
    for r in range(rows):
        x = 30
        
        #y_temp = y +(cell_size // 5)
        spinbox_row = tk.Spinbox(grille_frame, from_=0, to=cols, width=2)
        #spinbox_row.grid(row=r, column=0)
        grille_frame.create_window((x, y+cell_size/2), window=spinbox_row, anchor="e")
    
        temp = []
        for c in range(cols):
            cell = grille_frame.create_rectangle((x, y), (x + cell_size, y + cell_size), fill="white", outline= "black")
            temp.append(cell)
            x = x + cell_size
        y = y + cell_size
    
    x = y = 30
    for c in range(cols):
        spinbox_col = tk.Spinbox(grille_frame, from_=0, to=rows, width=2)
        grille_frame.create_window((x+cell_size/2, y), window=spinbox_col, anchor="s")
        x = x + cell_size
    
    grille_frame.update_idletasks()
    grille_frame.config(scrollregion=grille_frame.bbox("all"))

matrice_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame, text="Matrice", command=matrice)
matrice_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
def creer_hanjie():
    """ affiche une grille de cases blanches """
    grille_frame.delete("all")
    x = 30
    y = 30
    
    for r in range(rows):
        x = 30
        for c in range(cols):
            cell = grille_frame.create_rectangle((x, y), (x + cell_size, y + cell_size ), fill="white", outline= "black")
            x = x + cell_size
            print("coordonnées case:", grille_frame.coords(cell))
            
            grille_frame.bind("<Button-1>", click_1case)
        y = y + cell_size
    grille_frame.update_idletasks()
    print("canvaas taille", grille_frame.bbox("all"))
    grille_frame.config(scrollregion=grille_frame.bbox("all"))

grille_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame, text="create grid", command=creer_hanjie)
grille_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
def click_1case(event):
    """ change la couleur de la case par click simple, 1 case à la fois """
    print("clic souris", event.x, event.y)
    case = grille_frame.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    couleur_actuelle = grille_frame.itemcget(case, "fill")
    if couleur_actuelle == "white":
        nouvelle_couleur = "black"
    else:
        nouvelle_couleur = "white"
    grille_frame.itemconfigure(case, fill=nouvelle_couleur)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `(event.x, event.y)` is a coordinates relative to the top-left corner of the canvas, and it may not be the same as the coordinates relative to the *origin* or canvas if the view is scrolled.

You need to convert `(event.x, event.y)` to the real coordinates using `.canvasx()` and `.canvasy()`:

```py
def click_1case(event):
    """ change la couleur de la case par click simple, 1 case à la fois """
    ### get the real coordinates
    x, y = grille_frame.canvasx(event.x), grille_frame.canvasy(event.y)
    print("clic souris", event.x, event.y, x, y)
    case = grille_frame.find_closest(x, y) # used the real coordinates
    couleur_actuelle = grille_frame.itemcget(case, "fill")
    if couleur_actuelle == "white":
        nouvelle_couleur = "black"
    else:
        nouvelle_couleur = "white"
    grille_frame.itemconfigure(case, fill=nouvelle_couleur)
```

Note that you can also get the item under the clicked point by `.find_withtag("current")` instead:

```py
def click_1case(event):
    ### get the item under mouse cursor
    case = grille_frame.find_withtag("current")
    couleur_actuelle = grille_frame.itemcget(case, "fill")
    nouvelle_couleur = "black" if couleur_actuelle == "white" else "white"
    grille_frame.itemconfigure(case, fill=nouvelle_couleur)
```

Comment: Yes Thanks, It solves the bug for the position of the mouse. On the other hand, there is always an undeleted spinbox, but surprisingly, in my original code, I did not have this bug.